# Color shading with D3 comparative histogram

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, histogram

Edit: due to sizing, probably easiest to view the snippet full screen. Also, use buttons to see what each bars actual color is, which may be helpful.

I am working on an interactive, comparative histogram in D3, however I am struggling with setting the colors appropriately. See below for what I have so far.

```js
class App extends React.Component {

 constructor(props) { 
  super(props);
  
    this.state = { 
      selectedName: 'none'
    }
    
  this.chartProps = {
   myLightGrey: '#EEE',
   myMidGrey: '#888',
   myDarkGrey: '#333',
   chartWidth: 800, // Dont Change These, For Viewbox 
   chartHeight: 480, // Dont Change These, For Viewbox 
   padding: 80,
      margin: {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
   logoRadius: 800 / 36,
   svgID: "nbaStatHistograms"
  };
 }
  
  // Helper Functions
  generateStatData() {
    
    var data = [{"Pos":"PG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":37,"REB":6,"AST":3,"STL":0,"BLK":0,"TOV":2,"X3PM":6,"fullName":"Stephen-Curry"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":29,"REB":13,"AST":3,"STL":1,"BLK":3,"TOV":6,"X3PM":4,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":14,"REB":2,"AST":1,"STL":0,"BLK":1,"TOV":0,"X3PM":2,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"PG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":29,"REB":2,"AST":8,"STL":4,"BLK":0,"TOV":6,"X3PM":2,"fullName":"Stephen-Curry"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":25,"REB":8,"AST":6,"STL":0,"BLK":1,"TOV":2,"X3PM":4,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":21,"REB":4,"AST":3,"STL":0,"BLK":1,"TOV":2,"X3PM":3,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"PG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":30,"REB":4,"AST":5,"STL":3,"BLK":1,"TOV":2,"X3PM":4,"fullName":"Stephen-Curry"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":29,"REB":4,"AST":5,"STL":1,"BLK":0,"TOV":1,"X3PM":3,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":22,"REB":8,"AST":5,"STL":1,"BLK":1,"TOV":4,"X3PM":4,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"PG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":20,"REB":5,"AST":8,"STL":2,"BLK":0,"TOV":2,"X3PM":3,"fullName":"Stephen-Curry"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":31,"REB":11,"AST":6,"STL":1,"BLK":2,"TOV":4,"X3PM":4,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":18,"REB":2,"AST":3,"STL":0,"BLK":2,"TOV":1,"X3PM":2,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"PG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":27,"REB":6,"AST":8,"STL":1,"BLK":0,"TOV":5,"X3PM":3,"fullName":"Stephen-Curry"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":28,"REB":6,"AST":4,"STL":0,"BLK":2,"TOV":3,"X3PM":3,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":29,"REB":2,"AST":0,"STL":2,"BLK":0,"TOV":4,"X3PM":4,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"PG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":31,"REB":5,"AST":6,"STL":2,"BLK":1,"TOV":1,"X3PM":7,"fullName":"Stephen-Curry"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":19,"REB":7,"AST":4,"STL":0,"BLK":0,"TOV":1,"X3PM":2,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":15,"REB":5,"AST":6,"STL":0,"BLK":0,"TOV":3,"X3PM":1,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"PG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":21,"REB":8,"AST":4,"STL":3,"BLK":0,"TOV":2,"X3PM":3,"fullName":"Stephen-Curry"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":24,"REB":8,"AST":5,"STL":0,"BLK":3,"TOV":2,"X3PM":2,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":27,"REB":3,"AST":2,"STL":0,"BLK":1,"TOV":1,"X3PM":5,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"PG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":22,"REB":0,"AST":11,"STL":2,"BLK":0,"TOV":3,"X3PM":5,"fullName":"Stephen-Curry"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":25,"REB":7,"AST":7,"STL":0,"BLK":2,"TOV":4,"X3PM":4,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":15,"REB":2,"AST":2,"STL":1,"BLK":0,"TOV":2,"X3PM":3,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"PG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":16,"REB":5,"AST":4,"STL":2,"BLK":0,"TOV":1,"X3PM":2,"fullName":"Stephen-Curry"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":21,"REB":8,"AST":6,"STL":1,"BLK":3,"TOV":1,"X3PM":1,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":13,"REB":6,"AST":2,"STL":1,"BLK":2,"TOV":2,"X3PM":3,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"PG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":22,"REB":8,"AST":8,"STL":2,"BLK":1,"TOV":5,"X3PM":2,"fullName":"Stephen-Curry"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":28,"REB":5,"AST":3,"STL":1,"BLK":0,"TOV":1,"X3PM":6,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"PG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":22,"REB":4,"AST":9,"STL":1,"BLK":0,"TOV":2,"X3PM":3,"fullName":"Stephen-Curry"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":29,"REB":5,"AST":4,"STL":2,"BLK":2,"TOV":4,"X3PM":3,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":23,"REB":1,"AST":2,"STL":1,"BLK":0,"TOV":1,"X3PM":4,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":21,"REB":7,"AST":8,"STL":0,"BLK":0,"TOV":2,"X3PM":0,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":15,"REB":4,"AST":5,"STL":0,"BLK":0,"TOV":2,"X3PM":3,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"PG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":9,"REB":6,"AST":5,"STL":4,"BLK":0,"TOV":4,"X3PM":2,"fullName":"Stephen-Curry"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":24,"REB":3,"AST":3,"STL":1,"BLK":2,"TOV":3,"X3PM":2,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":13,"REB":7,"AST":3,"STL":0,"BLK":1,"TOV":1,"X3PM":3,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"PG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":35,"REB":5,"AST":5,"STL":0,"BLK":1,"TOV":2,"X3PM":4,"fullName":"Stephen-Curry"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":27,"REB":5,"AST":3,"STL":2,"BLK":2,"TOV":4,"X3PM":1,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":17,"REB":4,"AST":1,"STL":0,"BLK":0,"TOV":1,"X3PM":1,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"PG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":39,"REB":11,"AST":7,"STL":3,"BLK":0,"TOV":7,"X3PM":4,"fullName":"Stephen-Curry"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":23,"REB":10,"AST":1,"STL":2,"BLK":1,"TOV":2,"X3PM":1,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"PG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":24,"REB":5,"AST":6,"STL":1,"BLK":0,"TOV":6,"X3PM":3,"fullName":"Stephen-Curry"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":21,"REB":5,"AST":2,"STL":2,"BLK":0,"TOV":4,"X3PM":3,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":9,"REB":4,"AST":2,"STL":0,"BLK":1,"TOV":1,"X3PM":3,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"PG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":33,"REB":7,"AST":4,"STL":2,"BLK":0,"TOV":2,"X3PM":4,"fullName":"Stephen-Curry"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":29,"REB":4,"AST":1,"STL":1,"BLK":1,"TOV":4,"X3PM":5,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"PG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":27,"REB":4,"AST":6,"STL":1,"BLK":0,"TOV":1,"X3PM":3,"fullName":"Stephen-Curry"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":24,"REB":4,"AST":2,"STL":2,"BLK":2,"TOV":0,"X3PM":4,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":21,"REB":5,"AST":2,"STL":1,"BLK":1,"TOV":1,"X3PM":5,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"PG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":28,"REB":5,"AST":7,"STL":0,"BLK":0,"TOV":5,"X3PM":3,"fullName":"Stephen-Curry"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":29,"REB":7,"AST":5,"STL":1,"BLK":1,"TOV":6,"X3PM":3,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":20,"REB":3,"AST":2,"STL":0,"BLK":0,"TOV":0,"X3PM":4,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"PG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":23,"REB":6,"AST":10,"STL":3,"BLK":0,"TOV":4,"X3PM":3,"fullName":"Stephen-Curry"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":25,"REB":2,"AST":7,"STL":0,"BLK":4,"TOV":1,"X3PM":0,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":27,"REB":3,"AST":5,"STL":0,"BLK":0,"TOV":0,"X3PM":3,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"PG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":30,"REB":2,"AST":3,"STL":2,"BLK":0,"TOV":0,"X3PM":5,"fullName":"Stephen-Curry"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":24,"REB":3,"AST":7,"STL":1,"BLK":0,"TOV":4,"X3PM":2,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":19,"REB":5,"AST":4,"STL":0,"BLK":0,"TOV":1,"X3PM":2,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"PG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":31,"REB":5,"AST":11,"STL":1,"BLK":0,"TOV":2,"X3PM":5,"fullName":"Stephen-Curry"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":19,"REB":7,"AST":5,"STL":2,"BLK":1,"TOV":7,"X3PM":1,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":22,"REB":3,"AST":1,"STL":1,"BLK":0,"TOV":0,"X3PM":4,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":35,"REB":11,"AST":10,"STL":0,"BLK":2,"TOV":3,"X3PM":3,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":22,"REB":4,"AST":3,"STL":0,"BLK":0,"TOV":3,"X3PM":4,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":36,"REB":10,"AST":7,"STL":1,"BLK":5,"TOV":2,"X3PM":3,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":21,"REB":4,"AST":5,"STL":1,"BLK":0,"TOV":3,"X3PM":2,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":28,"REB":9,"AST":5,"STL":0,"BLK":3,"TOV":4,"X3PM":2,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":24,"REB":3,"AST":3,"STL":1,"BLK":0,"TOV":4,"X3PM":4,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":36,"REB":11,"AST":7,"STL":0,"BLK":2,"TOV":5,"X3PM":4,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":25,"REB":5,"AST":0,"STL":0,"BLK":0,"TOV":4,"X3PM":5,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":36,"REB":11,"AST":8,"STL":1,"BLK":3,"TOV":2,"X3PM":4,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":17,"REB":10,"AST":2,"STL":0,"BLK":0,"TOV":2,"X3PM":4,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":22,"REB":8,"AST":2,"STL":0,"BLK":2,"TOV":4,"X3PM":2,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":29,"REB":2,"AST":5,"STL":2,"BLK":0,"TOV":3,"X3PM":3,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":33,"REB":7,"AST":7,"STL":2,"BLK":4,"TOV":1,"X3PM":3,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":16,"REB":1,"AST":1,"STL":1,"BLK":2,"TOV":2,"X3PM":2,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":18,"REB":6,"AST":1,"STL":2,"BLK":2,"TOV":3,"X3PM":0,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":15,"REB":5,"AST":4,"STL":3,"BLK":0,"TOV":3,"X3PM":1,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":25,"REB":7,"AST":3,"STL":2,"BLK":5,"TOV":4,"X3PM":3,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":24,"REB":7,"AST":2,"STL":0,"BLK":0,"TOV":0,"X3PM":4,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":21,"REB":6,"AST":4,"STL":0,"BLK":3,"TOV":2,"X3PM":2,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":15,"REB":0,"AST":1,"STL":0,"BLK":1,"TOV":2,"X3PM":3,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":27,"REB":4,"AST":6,"STL":0,"BLK":0,"TOV":3,"X3PM":4,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":24,"REB":3,"AST":2,"STL":0,"BLK":0,"TOV":2,"X3PM":3,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"PG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":38,"REB":4,"AST":3,"STL":0,"BLK":0,"TOV":0,"X3PM":10,"fullName":"Stephen-Curry"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":20,"REB":5,"AST":9,"STL":1,"BLK":1,"TOV":1,"X3PM":2,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":21,"REB":0,"AST":5,"STL":0,"BLK":0,"TOV":3,"X3PM":5,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"PG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":32,"REB":5,"AST":8,"STL":1,"BLK":0,"TOV":3,"X3PM":6,"fullName":"Stephen-Curry"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":25,"REB":12,"AST":6,"STL":0,"BLK":4,"TOV":2,"X3PM":1,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":25,"REB":5,"AST":4,"STL":2,"BLK":1,"TOV":1,"X3PM":3,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"PG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":29,"REB":9,"AST":5,"STL":1,"BLK":0,"TOV":3,"X3PM":4,"fullName":"Stephen-Curry"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":28,"REB":3,"AST":4,"STL":0,"BLK":0,"TOV":1,"X3PM":6,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"PG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":45,"REB":6,"AST":3,"STL":3,"BLK":0,"TOV":2,"X3PM":8,"fullName":"Stephen-Curry"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":10,"REB":4,"AST":3,"STL":1,"BLK":1,"TOV":2,"X3PM":2,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"PG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":32,"REB":4,"AST":9,"STL":2,"BLK":0,"TOV":6,"X3PM":5,"fullName":"Stephen-Curry"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":19,"REB":5,"AST":1,"STL":0,"BLK":2,"TOV":0,"X3PM":3,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":40,"REB":4,"AST":4,"STL":1,"BLK":1,"TOV":5,"X3PM":6,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":26,"REB":6,"AST":6,"STL":2,"BLK":0,"TOV":3,"X3PM":2,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":12,"REB":5,"AST":2,"STL":0,"BLK":0,"TOV":2,"X3PM":0,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"PG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":24,"REB":6,"AST":9,"STL":1,"BLK":0,"TOV":1,"X3PM":2,"fullName":"Stephen-Curry"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":25,"REB":6,"AST":5,"STL":0,"BLK":1,"TOV":1,"X3PM":3,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":26,"REB":3,"AST":0,"STL":2,"BLK":0,"TOV":0,"X3PM":2,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"PG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":23,"REB":4,"AST":8,"STL":2,"BLK":0,"TOV":3,"X3PM":4,"fullName":"Stephen-Curry"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":32,"REB":5,"AST":8,"STL":3,"BLK":1,"TOV":3,"X3PM":4,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":17,"REB":4,"AST":2,"STL":1,"BLK":1,"TOV":2,"X3PM":3,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"PG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":30,"REB":9,"AST":4,"STL":1,"BLK":0,"TOV":6,"X3PM":6,"fullName":"Stephen-Curry"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":19,"REB":8,"AST":7,"STL":1,"BLK":0,"TOV":0,"X3PM":0,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":38,"REB":4,"AST":2,"STL":0,"BLK":1,"TOV":3,"X3PM":7,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"PG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":19,"REB":1,"AST":8,"STL":2,"BLK":0,"TOV":6,"X3PM":5,"fullName":"Stephen-Curry"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":26,"REB":7,"AST":5,"STL":0,"BLK":2,"TOV":4,"X3PM":4,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":8,"REB":1,"AST":1,"STL":2,"BLK":0,"TOV":1,"X3PM":2,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"PG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":32,"REB":6,"AST":7,"STL":0,"BLK":0,"TOV":1,"X3PM":8,"fullName":"Stephen-Curry"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":14,"REB":4,"AST":14,"STL":2,"BLK":2,"TOV":5,"X3PM":2,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":9,"REB":2,"AST":4,"STL":0,"BLK":0,"TOV":0,"X3PM":0,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"PG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":25,"REB":5,"AST":9,"STL":3,"BLK":0,"TOV":2,"X3PM":5,"fullName":"Stephen-Curry"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":28,"REB":10,"AST":11,"STL":2,"BLK":3,"TOV":4,"X3PM":6,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":25,"REB":5,"AST":3,"STL":1,"BLK":1,"TOV":3,"X3PM":7,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"PG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":49,"REB":4,"AST":5,"STL":2,"BLK":0,"TOV":1,"X3PM":8,"fullName":"Stephen-Curry"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":20,"REB":9,"AST":2,"STL":1,"BLK":1,"TOV":2,"X3PM":1,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":7,"REB":4,"AST":3,"STL":1,"BLK":2,"TOV":1,"X3PM":0,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"PG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":14,"REB":2,"AST":5,"STL":0,"BLK":0,"TOV":3,"X3PM":1,"fullName":"Stephen-Curry"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":17,"REB":2,"AST":3,"STL":1,"BLK":0,"TOV":0,"X3PM":0,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":27,"REB":6,"AST":3,"STL":2,"BLK":0,"TOV":3,"X3PM":3,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"PG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":23,"REB":5,"AST":6,"STL":2,"BLK":0,"TOV":6,"X3PM":3,"fullName":"Stephen-Curry"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":33,"REB":4,"AST":6,"STL":0,"BLK":0,"TOV":5,"X3PM":6,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":20,"REB":6,"AST":3,"STL":0,"BLK":0,"TOV":1,"X3PM":4,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"PG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":24,"REB":6,"AST":4,"STL":2,"BLK":0,"TOV":5,"X3PM":5,"fullName":"Stephen-Curry"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":31,"REB":6,"AST":7,"STL":0,"BLK":2,"TOV":1,"X3PM":0,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":16,"REB":1,"AST":5,"STL":2,"BLK":0,"TOV":0,"X3PM":2,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"PG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":21,"REB":5,"AST":5,"STL":1,"BLK":1,"TOV":3,"X3PM":2,"fullName":"Stephen-Curry"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":33,"REB":6,"AST":1,"STL":1,"BLK":1,"TOV":5,"X3PM":3,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":12,"REB":4,"AST":2,"STL":1,"BLK":0,"TOV":3,"X3PM":2,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"PG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":20,"REB":7,"AST":8,"STL":0,"BLK":0,"TOV":4,"X3PM":4,"fullName":"Stephen-Curry"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":24,"REB":9,"AST":4,"STL":1,"BLK":2,"TOV":1,"X3PM":4,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":18,"REB":5,"AST":4,"STL":0,"BLK":0,"TOV":3,"X3PM":2,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"PG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":17,"REB":4,"AST":8,"STL":2,"BLK":0,"TOV":2,"X3PM":3,"fullName":"Stephen-Curry"},{"Pos":"SF","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":10,"REB":6,"AST":6,"STL":0,"BLK":2,"TOV":1,"X3PM":0,"fullName":"Kevin-Durant"},{"Pos":"SG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":25,"REB":3,"AST":0,"STL":0,"BLK":0,"TOV":3,"X3PM":5,"fullName":"Klay-Thompson"},{"Pos":"PG","teamAbb":"GSW","PTS":22,"REB":9,"AST":7,"STL":0,"BLK":1,"TOV":3,"X3PM":3,"fullName":"Stephen-Curry"}];
    
    return data;
    
  } 
  round(number, precision) {
    var factor = Math.pow(10, precision);
    return Math.round(number * factor) / factor;
  }
  updateButtonColors(button, parent, self) {
    
    const {myLightGrey, myMidGrey, myDarkGrey} = self.chartProps;
    
    parent.selectAll("rect")
      .attr("fill", myLightGrey)
    parent.selectAll("text")
      .attr("fill", myDarkGrey)


    button.select("rect")
      .attr("fill", myDarkGrey)
    button.select("text")
      .attr("fill", myLightGrey)
  }
  xScaleFunc(self) {
    
    const {chartWidth, margin } = self.chartProps;
    const statData = self.generateStatData();
  
    // looks to be working correctly here
    
    return d3.scaleLinear() 
      .domain(d3.extent(statData, stat => stat.AST)).nice()
      .range([margin.left, chartWidth - margin.right]);
  } 
  yScaleFunc(self, maxY) {
    
    const { chartHeight, margin } = self.chartProps;
    const statData = self.generateStatData();
    
    return d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, maxY]).nice()
      .range([chartHeight - margin.bottom, margin.top])
  }  
 
  // Draw Graph Functions
  drawHistogram() {
    
    // 0. Setup | Scales and Other Constants
    // =======================================
    const { chartHeight, chartWidth, margin, myDarkGrey } = this.chartProps;
    const { xScaleFunc, yScaleFunc } = this;
    const xScale = xScaleFunc(this);
    const statData = this.generateStatData()
    
    const histogram = d3.histogram()
      .domain(xScale.domain())
      .thresholds(xScale.ticks(10))
    // ======
    
    
    // 1. Draw The Histogram For Each Guy
    // ===================================
    const histogramBars = d3.select('g.histogramBars');
    const allPlayers = [... new Set(statData.map(row => row.fullName))]
    
    // loop to find max Y for yScale
    let maxY = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < allPlayers.length; i++) {
      const playerStats = statData
        .filter(row => row.fullName == allPlayers[i])
        .map(row => row.AST)
      
      const playerBinnedData = histogram(playerStats)
      
      let thisYmax = d3.max(playerBinnedData, d => d.length)      
      maxY = (thisYmax > maxY) ? thisYmax : maxY; 
    }
    
    const yScale = yScaleFunc(this, maxY);
    
    // loop to create histogram for each player
    const colors = ['yellow', 'red', 'blue'];
    for(var i = 0; i < allPlayers.length; i++) {
      
      const playerStats = statData
        .filter(row => row.fullName == allPlayers[i])
        .map(row => row.AST)

      const playerBinnedData = histogram(playerStats)

      const playerBars = histogramBars
        .append("g")
        .selectAll(`.rect-${allPlayers[i]}`)
        .data(playerBinnedData)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
          .attr("class", `rect-${allPlayers[i]}`)
          .attr("x", d => xScale(d.x0) + 1)
          .attr("width", d => Math.max(0, xScale(d.x1) - xScale(d.x0) - 1))
          .attr("y", d => yScale(d.length))
          .attr("height", d => yScale(0) - yScale(d.length))
          .attr("fill", colors[i])
          .attr("stroke", myDarkGrey)
          .attr("stroke-width", 2)
          .attr("opacity", 0.5);
    }


    const xAxis = g => g
      .attr("transform", `translate(0,${chartHeight - margin.bottom})`)
      .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickSizeOuter(0))
      .call(g => g.append("text")
          .attr("x", chartWidth - margin.right)
          .attr("y", -4)
          .attr("fill", "#000")
          .attr("font-weight", "bold")
          .attr("text-anchor", "end")
          .text('X Axis Name Goes Here'))
            
    histogramBars.append("g")
      .call(xAxis);
  
    const yAxis = g => g
      .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},0)`)
      .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale))
      .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove())
      .call(g => g.select(".tick:last-of-type text").clone()
          .attr("x", 4)
          .attr("text-anchor", "start")
          .attr("font-weight", "bold")
          .text('# of Games'))

    histogramBars.append("g")
      .call(yAxis);
  
  }
  
  drawNameHoverButtons() {
    
    // Setup Constants
    // ==================
    const { myLightGrey, myMidGrey, myDarkGrey } = this.chartProps;
    const { updateButtonColors } = this;
    const bWidth= 75; 
    const bHeight= 25; 
    const bSpace= 5; 

    const statData = this.generateStatData()    
    const allPlayers = [... new Set(statData.map(row => row.fullName))]
    const nameHoverButtons = d3.select('g.nameHoverButtons')
    
    // ====
    
    // Add buttons 
    // ==================
    const self = this;
    const buttonGroup = nameHoverButtons.selectAll("g.nameButton")
      .data(allPlayers)
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "button")
      .style("cursor", "pointer")
    
    buttonGroup.append("rect")
      .attr("class","buttonRect")
      .attr("width",bWidth)
      .attr("height",bHeight)
      .attr("x", (d,i) => 500 + (bWidth+bSpace)*i)
      .attr("y", 0)
      .attr("rx", 4) // rx and ry give the buttons rounded corners
      .attr("ry", 4)
      .attr("fill", myLightGrey)
      .attr("stroke", myDarkGrey)
      .attr("stroke-width", "0.1em")
    
    // adding text to each toggle button group
    buttonGroup.append("text")
      .attr("class","buttonText")
      .attr("font-family", "arial")
      .attr("font-size", "0.6em")
      .attr("x", (d,i) => 500 + (bWidth+bSpace)*i + bWidth/2)
      .attr("y", 10)
      .attr("text-anchor","middle")
      .attr("dominant-baseline","central")
      .attr("fill", '#222')
      .text(d => d)
    
    buttonGroup
      .on("click", function(d,i) {
        updateButtonColors(d3.select(this), d3.select(this.parentNode), self)
        self.setState({selectedName: allPlayers[i]})
      })
      .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
        if (d3.select(this).select("rect").attr("fill") != myDarkGrey) {
          d3.select(this)
            .select("rect")
            .attr("fill", myMidGrey); // lol almost here keep trying
        }
      
        d3.selectAll(`g.histogramBars rect`)
          .attr('opacity', 0.1)
      
        d3.selectAll(`.rect-${allPlayers[i]}`)
          .attr('z-index', 3)
          .attr('opacity', 1)
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d, i) {
        if (d3.select(this).select("rect").attr("fill") != myDarkGrey) {
          d3.select(this)
            .select("rect")
            .attr("fill", myLightGrey);
        }
      
        d3.selectAll(`g.histogramBars rect`)
          .attr('opacity', 0.5)
      
        d3.selectAll(`.rect-${allPlayers[i]}`)
          .attr('z-index', 1)
          .attr('opacity', 0.5)
      })
  }
  
  drawStatButtons() {
    
  }
 // When component mounts, get
 componentDidMount() {
  const { chartHeight, chartWidth, svgID } = this.chartProps;

  d3.select(`#${svgID}`)
   .attr('width', '100%')
   .attr('height', '100%')
   .attr('viewBox', "0 0 " + chartWidth + " " + chartHeight)
   .attr('preserveAspectRatio', "xMaxYMax");
    
    this.drawHistogram()
    this.drawNameHoverButtons()
 }

 render() {
    
    const { svgID } = this.chartProps;
   return (
   <div ref="scatter">
    <svg id={svgID}>
     <g className="histogramBars" />
          <g className="nameHoverButtons" />
     <g className="points" />
    </svg>
   </div>
  )
 }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-tip/0.8.0-alpha.1/d3-tip.js"></script>

<div id='root'>
  FUCKING WORK
</div>
```

My issue I think is a simple one, but hard to describe typing, but I will try.

The 3 main colors used in this graph are red, blue and yellow. However, if you look in column 3, you will see blue, darker blue, and purple. This is because of the order of my for loop, where the histogram for yellow is plotted first, then the histogram for red, then the histogram for blue bars. Since the blue bars are plotted last, the color with by far the most emphasis is blue, even though I've used an opacity of 0.5.

For example, if you were to change the line in my code where I create the color array, by reordering the colors, you'll see a new emphasis placed on whichever color is plotted last.

Instead of blue, dark blue, purple, I would like to see the yellow, red and blue in each bar column. If it is the case for a particular histogram column that yellow has the lowest y value (say y=3), then red (y=5), then blue (y=8), I would like the color of emphasis for the bottom part of the bar (0-3) to be yellow, for the middle part of the bar (3-5) to be red, and for the top part of the bar to be blue (5-8).

Please let me know if I can elaborate more on what I'm looking for. Otherwise, appreciate in advance any help I can get with this!

Comment: I'd convert the histogram data into a stacked bar chart and extend the bar to 0 when the buttons are triggered.

Comment: thats a good idea. didn't think that histogram data format was holding me back, but seems like it might be for what im trying to do